# Hazelcast. Failed to serialize

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, apache-camel, hazelcast

I used

- Apache Camel 2.23.4;
- Hazelcast 3.12.6.

Updating Apache Camel:

- Apache Camel 3.2.0;
- Hazelcast 3.12.6.

After updating apache camel when adding an object to the **hazelcast IMap** i get a Serialization exception.

```
@lombok.Value
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
public class Tasks implements Serializable {
  private String id;
  private String correlationId;
  private String key;
  private Map<String, Object> body;
  private Map<String, Object> props;
  private Boolean timer;
}
```

When an object placed on the map gets an exception

```
IMap<String, Tasks> IMapTasks=hazelcastInstance.getMap(TASK_MAP_NAME);
IMapTasks.put(task.getId(), taks);
```

Stacktrace:

```
 Error receiving Notification Task control message : Failed to serialize 'home.test.service.model.Task'
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'home.test.service.model.Task'
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:82) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toData(NodeEngineImpl.java:319) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.toData(AbstractDistributedObject.java:68) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:133) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:125) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
.
. 
.
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.LongStringHelper$ByteArrayLongString
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2438) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems the name of the model is not the same. `Error receiving Notification Task control message : Failed to serialize 'home.test.service.model.Task'`  and `public class  Tasks implements Serializable`

Comment: @HadiJ Model Name Found. **Error receiving Notification Task control message : Failed to serialize 'home.test.service.model.Task'** this message from my try{} catch(Exception e){}, Exception message:"Failed to serialize 'home.test.service.model.Task"

Answer (score 2):

Use of `@lombok.Value` makes the fields final.

`java.io.Serializable` requires a noargs constuctor

So you might need

```
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
public class Tasks implements Serializable {
  private String id;
  private String correlationId;
  private String key;
```

Comment: it did not help me

Comment: See `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.LongStringHelper$ByteArrayLongString`. What objects are you putting in the `body` and `props` fields